# Android CI/CD with Fastlane and GitHub Actions: "fastlane" command not found at master branch

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions, fastlane, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to implement a CI/CD workflow for my Android project using Github Actions and Fastlane. I created a workflow to build and APK file and upload it to Firebase App Distribution. My workflow is triggered and succeed when I pushed to my development branch and uploads the APK file to Firebase App Distribution as expected.

[image]

But the same workflow is failed on master branch (without any code changes) with error: "bundler: command not found: fastlane"

[image]

When I call the same fastlane action on my local device, it works and uploads the APK to Firebase App Distribution.

Here is my lane:

```
    lane :beta do |options|

        version = options[:versionChange]
        runUnitTests = options[:runUnitTests]
        gitUserMail = options[:gitUserMail]
        gitUserName = options[:gitUserName]

        # 1- Make version code and name incrementation

        if version.nil? || version == 'patch'
            gradle(task: "doPatchVersionIncrement")
        end

        if version == 'major'
            gradle(task: "doMajorVersionIncrement")
        end

        if version == 'minor'
            gradle(task: "doMinorVersionIncrement")
        end

        gradle(task: "doBuildNumberIncrement")
        gradle(task: "doBuildNumberBetaIncrementValueIncrement")

        # 2- Run unit tests for all variants
        if runUnitTests.nil? && runUnitTests != 'false'
                gradle(task: "clean")
                gradle(task: "test")
        end

        # 3- Build Release APK
                gradle(task: "clean")
                gradle(task: 'assemble', build_type: 'Release')

        # 4- push version bump commit

        properties = property_file_read(file: "app/version.properties")
        versionMajor = properties['VERSION_NAME_MAJOR']
        versionMinor = properties['VERSION_NAME_MINOR']
        versionPatch = properties['VERSION_NAME_PATCH']
        versionCode = properties['VERSION_CODE']
        versionName = "#{versionMajor}.#{versionMinor}.#{versionPatch}"

        if !gitUserMail.nil? && !gitUserMail.empty? && !gitUserName.nil? && !gitUserName.empty?
              sh "git config --global user.email #{gitUserMail}; git config --global user.name #{gitUserName}"
        end

        sh "git add .. ; git commit -m 'Version bump : versionCode = #{versionCode} | versionName = #{versionName}'"
        push_to_git_remote

        # 5- Send APK to Firebase
        firebase_app_distribution(app: "MY_FIREBASE_APP_ID", groups: "qa-team")
  end
```

Here is my .yml file for GitHub Action:

```
name: Deploy Release APK to Firebase App Distribution

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  upload_firebase_app_distribution:
    name: Upload to Release Apk to Firebase App Distribution
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.3

      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.6'
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Distribute app with  App Distribution 
        run: bundle exec fastlane beta version:patch runUnitTests:false gitUserMail:user@company.com gitUserName:user_name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Updated Ruby version
2. Installed Fastlane after Ruby
3. Added "android" command after "fastlane" command

Then problem is solved. Here is the fixed workflow:

```
name: Deploy Release APK to Firebase App Distribution
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy_to_beta:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.7.2'

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        run: bundle install

      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        run: bundle exec fastlane android beta version:patch runUnitTests:false gitUserMail:user@company.com gitUserName:user_name
```